# GTM is not tracking the events in Chrome Browser inside I-Frame

Tags: google-chrome, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

for Event tracking, GTM has been configured and used in the application. GTM tracks event
correctly and displays the correct result in **Google Analytics when using Firefox browser** however its not detecting/tracking the events when switch to chrome browser.

Note: The Application is within the I-frame for event tracking.

Comment: wich kind of event are you tracking? are you using a custom html?

Comment: We are tracking button clicks using its unique ID via GTM Event.

Comment: could you clear your cache and try again?

Comment: We tries clearing the cache but it is not working.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Any update on this. Were you able to resolve it ?